# Disable ipv4 with /etc/sysctl.conf | GNU/LINUX Debian 11

Tags: networking, debian, ip, sysctl

I can `disable ipv6` as `su` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` on my `GNU/LINUX Debian 11` with

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

and restart with

```
/sbin/sysctl -p
```

when i try to `disable ipv4` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` and restart with

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.disable_ipv4 = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.disable_ipv4 = 1
```

i get error message

`sysctl:  cannot stat ....`

there is no `disable_ipv4` in `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/`

How can i `disable ipv4` like i do with `disable ipv6` with the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't disable IPv4 in the `sysctl.conf`.

You have two options: you can drop the IP-address so that no external traffic can reach your device (might as well just block everything with `ufw`?). But this is not persistent and would have to be done after every reboot, maybe using a bash script and `cron`.

```
ip -4 addr show eth0 # reveals your IP-address with CIDR suffix, e.g. 128.199.175.162/18
ip addr del 128.199.175.162/18 dev eth0
```

The second option is to edit a file so that IPv4 is disabled *at boot*. There is an article on [DigitalOcean](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/networking/ipv6/how-to/disable-ipv4/) that describes it for Debian 9.

Also have a look at this [Serverfault post](https://serverfault.com/questions/256811/how-to-completely-dynamically-disable-ipv4-stack-from-linux) which explains a few things about the IPv4 stack.